# Where is the List with all loaded Kernel Moduls located

Tags: linux, list, kernel

I need help with one of my task. I'm writing a Linux Kernel Module which should print all loaded modules (just like print_modules but each one in a different line). I'm not allowed to read files (like /proc/modules).

My Problem is that I'm not able to find the corresponding List in the Kernel so that I can access it with my C code.

I already search Modules.c/.h and found the Modul struct where a doubly-linked list is stored, but I cant access the other moduls with that one.

Hope my problem is clear and somebody can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a kernel expert (at all ;-), but where does `print_modules` get its information, and couldn't you clone that function and add a `\n` to it's print statement? Sorry if you have considered this, but you didn't make it clear why you can't use that. Good luck. (Will delete this comment after a while).

Comment: thats what we wanted to do, but this methode (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L4052 just hit ctrl+f + "print_module") needs to many arguments, which we cant locate aswell =/ i was told there should be a pretty easy solution by just iterating through the list

Comment: Found the answer: the list can be found within the own Kernel Module (with a function get_module). There is an object Module->List, which is a doubly-linked list.
With list.h we can get the Module of list.next/.prev

Comment: @majoraskid write an answer and mark it as a correct, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from my comment:

The list can be found within the own Kernel Module (with a function get_module). There is an object Module->List, which is a doubly-linked list. With list.h we can get the Module of list.next/.prev